# Drawing bicarbonate ion in different way

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure, lewis-structure

I don't know why can't I draw $\ce{[HCO3]-}$ like that:

[image: [HCO3]-]

I tried to draw it like that and checked everything.
I checked formal charge and all was good.
Why they draw it OH I know its also alright but whats wrong with my draw? 24e checked and formal charge checked.
The upper left oxygen has 6 non bonding electrons the next one has 4 non bonding electrons. It's coordinative bond.

[image: Hand-drawn structure for [HCO3]-]

Comment: I suggest to review grammar, bring formatting in order and append the relevant comments into the question. Is [this structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XF1x.png) is what you have in mind?

Comment: there is no picture its black screen . i mean its simple question everyone can understand with the picture i drew why making life hard ?  if i knew the answer and someone asked i'll just tell him simple as that

Comment: It's a PNG with alpha-channel enabled. Change the background from black to another color or just enable checkerboard preview for images in your browser.

Comment: assuming this is the picture i want is it right to draw like that ?

Comment: I don't know, you tell us. I just assumed this is the Lewis structure you tried to display.

Comment: i will add a photo of my drawing through iphone but i am sure no one will answer and i will be wasting my time but i'll try maybe one good person shows up

Comment: I have not enough points for a comment, but all the downratings are for the insufficient formatting of the question, not enough information on what you want, no effort in your work. What you drew and i believe you want to draw is the conjugate base (deprotonated form of the acid) of [performic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performic_acid). If not, then you may have [carbonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid) in mind, if so then you drew the wrong structure. Your question is not clear to me, but you may want to try ACD ChemSketch (free) software for drawing molecules.

Comment: Technical note: please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. For drawing chemical strictures, see [Software section of our Wiki](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37880/41328).

Comment: Do you really suppose the strongly oxidizing hydroperoxide anion group directly bound to reducing aldehyde group would survive their marriage?? It is rather a recipe for an unstable explosive.

Comment: my course is general chemistry I am majoring as civil enginner so i dont know what you are talking about but in highschool i do remember OH group  the thing is i dont know whats wrong with my model ?

Comment: As mentioned in the Andrew's post,your structure does not belong to bicarbonate anion, but to performate ( peroxyformate ) anion, what are different compounds.

Answer (score 5):

Who said you couldn’t? You absolutely can. What you have shown is [performic acid](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Performic-acid) $\ce{CH2O3}$ (or at least its conjugate base). Just to clarify, it is obviously different to [carbonic acid](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Carbonic-acid) $\ce{H2CO3}$.

Comment: i have answers that only show resonance drawings which are 2 models and didn't have my drawing

Comment: Your drawing is a valid molecular structure, it just isn't the structure of bicarbonate. As pointed out above, you have drawn the structure of performate (the deprotonated form of performic acid).

Comment: @RaziAwad what you have drawn is a peroxyacid which has vastly different properties to carbonic acid (which you were trying to draw), which is not, due to them having different functional groups.